# Вопросы с заданиями

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Допустим есть следующий вопрос:

> Как нарисовать ёлочку?
>
> Давайте вместе придумаем как можно нарисовать ёлочку,
> язык может быть любой.
> Вот пример решения на Python2:
> `print 'п ==>>>>,'  # срубили елочку`
>
> [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc) [любой-язык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba)

Подлежат ли подобные вопросы закрытию, если да, то почему?
Много ответов - это не проблема, до тех пор пока ответы короткие (причина "невозможно дать лаконичный ответ") и пока вопрос не приводит к спорам (причина "вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии").

Вопрос подразумевает большое количество решений на разных языках. Хорошо ли это? Следует ли задать сразу несколько вопросов для разных языков, из тех, что интересуют автора (например C++, Python, Haskell)?

Comment: А примеры есть?

Comment: А откуда желание закрывать их?

Comment: @Qwertiy пока нет, но я хочу задать один или несколько

Comment: Ну попробуй - посмотрим, что получится. Но вообще, http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Qwertiy - а вот и пример - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488217/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83

Comment: У вас в теле вопроса совершенно другая проблема озвучена. Переименовал вопрос. Если не согласны - откатите и сформулируйте точнее плиз

Answer (score 1):

Мне не кажется, что такой вопрос подразумевает решения на *разных* языках. Он подразумевает решения на *любом* языке. Это значит, что ответ

```
#include <iostream>
int main() { std::cout << "п ==>>>>,"; }
```

будет не новым ответом, а просто клоном вашего ответа на Питоне.

А дублирующие ответы можно давать хоть на разных языках, хоть на одном (с точностью до переименования переменных, а то и без него).

Comment: это в случае со Срубленной Ёлочкой. Но вот например более сложный алгоритм, например "как написать quicksort" - будет выглядеть на разных языках по разному.

Comment: Ну, тогда можно описание («найти осевой элемент, разделить на те, которые меньше осевого и больше, отсортировать рекурсивно, соединить»). И примерную реализацию. Низкоуровневые оптимизации наподобие «переставлять данные в том же массиве» являются языко-специфическими и по идее не должны быть основной частью ответа. Хотя их стоит упомянуть, конечно.

Comment: @Abyx: Для иллюстрации идеи гораздо лучше [Хаскель](https://wiki.haskell.org/Introduction#Quicksort_in_Haskell).

Comment: @Abyx, а мне кажется, что ответ с примерами на разных языках интересен. В таком ответе можно красиво показать сильные и слабые стороны разных языков, их приспособленность для решения задач разного плана (я, прочитав вопрос, почему-то решил что Вы хотите закрывать подобные, но, как выяснилось, наоборот...)

Comment: @avp, или можно показать слабые или сильные стороны исполнителя, что более вероятно.

Comment: @ixSci,  вот читатель, сопоставляя себя с парами  "язык-исполнитель" и будет делать выбор.

Answer (score 1):

Я против подобных вопросов потому что они не несут никакой ценности, мы же не пытаемся превратиться в википедию? В таких вопросах нельзя поставить зелёную галочку, потому как правильного ответа нет и быть не может. А это противоречит всей сути сайта. Кроме того, человек подписывается на конкретные языки и если не добавить все метки, то он его попросту не увидит.

Если интересна реализация того или иного алгоритма на нескольких языках, то стоит создать N вопросов с метками этих языков и, возможно, добавить перекрестные ссылки в сами вопросы.

Comment: подписывайтесь на [tag:любой-язык]

Comment: @Abyx, а много ли людей знают об этой метке и подпишутся на неё?

Comment: Я не знаю всех меток, но когда я встречаю интересную, я подписываюсь на неё. Думаю, так же могут делать и другие.

Comment: @VladD, Вы пользуетесь главной, там видите метки?

Comment: @ixSci: Ну да, около каждого вопроса пишутся его метки.

Comment: @VladD, просто я не вижу других вопросов, только те, метки которых мне интересны. И, полагаю, я не один такой.

Comment: @ixSci: А вы просматриваете только группы по меткам? о_О

Comment: @VladD, я вот [так](http://stackexchange.com/filters/217361/?sort=newest) вижу РуСО

Comment: @ixSci: Ах, там есть _фильтры_! Не знал. Век живи, век учись :) Я просматриваю просто [главную страницу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @VladD, я тоже так раньше делал. Но использование фильтров очень экономит мне время, поэтому я больше на главную вообще не смотрю